# Why is Ocaml not a "first choice for server-side development"

Tags: ocaml

In an old [Stevey blog rant](http://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/more-ocaml), Steve Yegge says that although he really likes Ocaml, he thinks it's not ideal for server-side development.

Does anyone know what are the key issues that "keep it [Ocaml] from being a first choice for server-side development"?

Thanks,

JDelage

Comment: Note that OCaml is used in several major server-side developments including the MyLife search engine, the XenServer management tool stack and Jane St. Capital's own automated trading software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some commentary from a Hacker News thread on the subject: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=112506

Comment: Pretty retarded reasons if they are the ones Steve had in mind. I hope you take them with a grain of salt.